# Hide/Show NavigationBar & Toolbar on tap

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to hide my navigationBar and toolbars on tap, similar to the way the Photos application works.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to animate the y value of UINavigationBar and UIToolBar like this

```
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
rect.origin.y = -40;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope this helps you too.

A.

Answer (score 11):

This works too :)

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: This seems to have the side effect of making the current view slide up along with the navigation bar.  That's fine, but if you want the navigation bar to partially obscure the view, and then "slide out of the way", Alberto's answer does the trick.

Comment: When applying this solution, for some reason this didn't work reliably for me when I put it into a `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear`. Instead, putting this code into the `NavigationControllerDelegate.navigationController(:willShow:animated:)` method worked better. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336350/ios-hide-the-navigation-bar-for-only-one-viewcontroller-which-is-root-of-the-ui

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8, you can simply achieve by this:

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can still use the

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

and you can stop your view from sliding up when the navigation/ toolbar shows. You can have your navigation/tool bar fade in and out over the view without sliding the view. Try this code it did work for me.

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

that is if you are currently on the view controller.