# how to detect a "quick touch" on a UITableView for the purpose of toggling to/from full screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

What is the coding to detect a "quick touch" on a UITableView for the purpose of toggling to/from full screen?

In particular this is because the user is on a UITableView they would still need the ability to drag the list of items up/down, and potentially click on a cell/row to dig deeper.  But if they touched quickly then this could be the trigger to toggle between full-screen mode (i.e. nav bar & tool bar).

Background - When I say toggling to/from full screen I'm refering to carrying out what is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605492/hide-show-navigation-tool-bar-on-tap), however in this answer there was no mention in terms of how to plug this into the callbacks for a UITableView which is being displayed within a UINavigationController stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to put up this as a possible answer, the answer being there is no relative straight way to achieve what I've asked for this.  That is a way for a tap or double-tap to be detected in a UITableView page, which is already picking up row touches and scroll up/down etc.

Haven't verified whether this is the case or not, but people could up-vote this answer if they believe this to be true.  (also waiting on sample from ypk who perhaps has an answer)

Answer (score 1):

The following code might help you

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    timeStampStart = event.timestamp;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    timeStampEnd = event.timestamp;
    touchDuration = timeStampEnd - timeStampStart;

    if(touchDuration > smallTimeStamp)
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [self zoomMyTableView];
}
```

Comment: thanks ypk - can I ask how does this fit in with the normal selection of a row in a table, or scrolling a table, or drilling down into a cell details?  Touch the could you highlighted take precedence?  If yes, is there anything else one has to do to make sure if the touch isn't a very short one that the other scenarios will still proceed ok?  thanks again

Comment: One more thing that I am missing is, you need add `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` in `toucesBegan`. You need implement these in your `UITableView` subclass. By this still your table views scrolling, selection will work, since we are sending the touch events to `super`, when touch timestamp is more than our minimum value.

Comment: actually this doesn't work for me - I'm using the simulator to test - I can't click on the simulator on the rows in the tableview and get any of these methods to trigger?  So I have a UITableView within a UINavigationController, and the table itself is based on a subclassed/custom UITableViewCell

Comment: I have done a sample example for you. If you want, tell me your email id, I will mail it to you asap.

Comment: its:  greg dot hauptmann at gmail dot com ypk thanks - remember I've got a UITableView showing on the page however...which I think is what's complicating things (I'm not sure if it's possible with a UITableView without a lot of work)