# Hide and show navigation bar with tap gesture

Tags: iphone, view, navigation, gesture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide/Show Navigation & Tool Bar on tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605492/hide-show-navigation-tool-bar-on-tap)

This is the void I'm using to hide the Navigation Bar in one of the views.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

How to tap the screen to hide and show the navigation bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you wish something like that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
                             self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideShowNavigation)] autorelease];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void) hideShowNavigation
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Added the code making the navigation controller overlap the view, instead of "pushing the view down" to make place for it.

Comment: I have a table view in my view but the above suggested approach is actually stopping me to select the table row...any other alternative?

Comment: I guess tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; should help